# What is a Fourier Symbol

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I was wondering what **exactly** the term *Fourier symbol*, or sometimes said *the symbol of the Fourier transform* means. Also, are any books that cover this topic in detail?

**Edit:**
After the comments, I have come to realise I mean to ask either: what is the symbol of the Fourier transform *operator*, or also known as Fourier multiplier.

Are there are good *recommended* texts that cover the topic of symbols of operators, and the Fourier transform, well?

Comment: If you can cite a source in which you've seen such terminology, I'll try updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: The fourier symbol (likely) just means to apply the fourier transform. Depending the context you're working in, the fourier transform may either be a function $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{C}^d \to \mathbb{C}^d$ for some finite $d$ (in which case you are dealing with the discrete fourier transform), or it may be a function $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{C}}$. Here $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{C}}$ is just a shorthand notation for a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Google search for "Fourier symbol" brings up at least one set of lecture notes that includes a definition (see [section 4.3](https://services.math.duke.edu/~jtwong/math551-2019/lectures/Transforms1_Fourier.pdf))

Comment: Might mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)

Comment: @J.G. I have heard this term being used in discussion, and I cannot provide an explicit reference. Although I think, as -cmk mentioned, I mean Fourier multiplier/symbol of the operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are interested in the symbol $P$ of of a pseudo-differential operator $T$ on $\mathbb R^n$ (or other...), the latter described by (up to choices)
$$
Tf(y) \;=\; \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{i\langle y,\xi\rangle}\; P(\xi,y) \Big(\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-i\langle \xi,x\rangle} \; f(x)\;dx\Big)\;d\xi
$$
This generalizes (in one way) the idea that Fourier transform converts constant-coefficient differential operators to multiplications by polynomials $P(\xi)$.

G. Folland's books (both Tata intro to PDEs and fuller textbook on PDEs) give good settings for and intros to simple cases of pseudo-differential operators. Many other sources (such as L. Hormander's books on PDE) treat general cases, which may obscure points of interest for a person new to the ideas.

Comment: This is precisely what I mean, thank you for providing references to this also. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's the $\mathcal{F}$ or $\tilde{}$ in definitions such as$$\mathcal{F}(f(x))(k):=\tilde{f}(k):=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x)\exp(-2\pi ik\cdot x)d^nx.$$